# Iterating Map of Map of Map in freemarker

Tags: templates, freemarker

I need to iterate over this map in **freemarker** language.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
       Map<String, Map<String, Map<String,String>>> map = new HashMap<>();
}
```

on the basis of each string i need to get map then again on the basis of string again map is needed.
thanks

Comment: If this is Java, you can use `Map.entrySet`. [Reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46898/how-to-efficiently-iterate-over-each-entry-in-a-map).

Comment: if you're using java-8 then `map.forEach((k, v) -> {
             ....
            v.forEach((e, a) -> {
                ....
                a.forEach((b, c) -> {
                    ...
                });
            });
        });` would suffice

Comment: thanks for your answers but i need to implement iteration in freemarker

Comment: @devtest I'm not sure about freemaker, but are you saying none of below answer works for you ?? If yes, then you must check, if you are really working on Java

Comment: @Ravi thanks for your answer, in java i can do but i need to iterate it in freemarker

Comment: @devtest Then it is not java. please select the tag correctly. I have removed anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems there is three level nested map, you can drill down using [list](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_builtins_hash.html) and you can show both [key and value](https://freemarker.apache.org/docs/ref_directive_list.html#ref.directive.list)

> Listing hashes is very similar, but you need to provide two variable names after the as; one for the hash key, and another for the associated value.

```
<#list map?values as vals>
  <#list vals?values  as innervals>
    <#list innervals as name, innerValue>
      ${name} value = ${innerValue}
    </#list>
  </#list>
</#list>
```

Comment: Can you open a new question?